# How to check date and time individually in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

In my SQL table have column like `startDate  - DATETIME`(data type) And  it gives format like

```
  `2013-08-08 06:30:00`
```

And i have two fields `dateonly - 2013-08-08`(value) `timeonly - 06:30:00`(value).

Now i want to query to check these two fields values with database value.

Hear two comparisons first check `dateonly` field is greater then or not and next check `timeonly` field is greater then or not.

is this possible in Mysql?

please help me in writing query

Answer (score 3):

for date you can use this

```
     WHERE DATE_FORMAT(datecolumn,'%Y-%m-%d') > 'some date here'
```

for time

```
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(datetimecolumn,%T) < 'sometime'
```

or use functions `date(datetimecolumn)` , `time(datetimecolumn)`

try this

```
    select * from Demo d where DATE(d.startDate)< 'dateonly'
```

or

```
  select * from Demo d where DATE_FORMAT(d.startDate ,'%Y-%m-%d')< 'dateonly'
```

Comment: Thanks for replay ... And compare to time TIME(d.startTime)<'timeonly'       ... is it sufficient???

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this two functions:

`Date(startDate)` and `Time(startDate)` which can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: in my query select * from Demo d where d.startDate.DATE()<datonly .This query works for me?????

Comment: @java no check how you will use it in my answer

Comment: `Select * form Demo where DATE(startdate)>'01-0-2013'`
or
`SELECT *, DATE(startdate) as DateOnlyStartDate FROM Demo`